# python pandas - dividing column by another column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a column to my `DataFrame` which is the product of division of two other columns, like so:

```
df['$/hour'] = df['$']/df['hours']
```

This works fine, but if the value in `['hours']` is less than `1`, then the `['$/hour']` value is greater than the value in `['$']`, which is not what I want.

Is there a way of controlling the operation so that if `['hours'] < 1` then `df['$/hour'] = df['$']`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print df
    hours  $
0       0  8
1       0  9
2       0  9
3       3  6
4       6  4
5       3  7
6       5  5
7      10  1
8       9  3
9       3  6
10      5  4
11      5  7

df['$/hour'] = np.where(df['hours'] < 1, df['hours'], df['$']/df['hours'])
print df
    hours  $    $/hour
0       0  8  0.000000
1       0  9  0.000000
2       0  9  0.000000
3       3  6  2.000000
4       6  4  0.666667
5       3  7  2.333333
6       5  5  1.000000
7      10  1  0.100000
8       9  3  0.333333
9       3  6  2.000000
10      5  4  0.800000
11      5  7  1.400000
```

Answer (score 8):

```
df['$/hour'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['$'] if x['$'] < 1 else x['$']/x['hours'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also filter and select the indexes to set with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['$/hour'].loc[df['hours']>=1] = df['$']/df['hours']
df['$/hour'].loc[df['hours']<1] = df['$']
```

Comment: This will raise a *KeyError* if the column `$/hour` does not exist beforehand. I would suggest using `df.loc[df['hours']>=1, '$/hour'] = df['$']/df['hours']` and `df.loc[df['hours']<1, '$/hour'] = df['$']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df['$/hour'] = (df['$'] / df['hours']).mask(df['hours'] < 1, df['$'])
```

If the condition `df['hours'] < 1` is met the values from column `$` are taken, otherwise `$` is divided by `hours`.