# group dataframe by column, process values and normalize other column based on processed values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-re

I have a dataframe `df` with two columns, `foo` and `bar`:

```
             foo       bar
0   2410_030_GCD  0.012093
1   2410_030_GCD  0.012789
2   2410_030_GCD  0.014205
3   2410_010_GCD  0.016280
4   2410_010_GCD  0.019738
5   6122_020_LCM  0.025806
6   6122_020_LCM  0.030336
7   6122_020_LCM  0.034753
8   6122_020_LCM  0.042229
9   3456_030_SGD  0.025792
10  3456_030_SGD  0.030255
11  3456_030_SGD  0.034683
12  3456_030_SGD  0.042194
```

For each group of rows where `foo` has the same value, I want to extract the first substring of 4 consecutive digits from 'foo' (i.e., `'2410'` if `foo = '2410_030_GCD'`), convert to a `float`, divide by 1000 and then divide the values of `bar` by the resulting value, storing the result in a new column called `baz`. In other words, the output has to be

```
             foo       bar        baz
0   2410_030_GCD  0.012093  0.0050178
1   2410_030_GCD  0.012789  0.0053066
2   2410_030_GCD  0.014205  0.0058942
3   2410_010_GCD  0.016280  0.0067552
4   2410_010_GCD  0.019738  0.0081900
5   6122_020_LCM  0.025806  0.0042153
6   6122_020_LCM  0.030336  0.0049552
7   6122_020_LCM  0.034753  0.0056767
8   6122_020_LCM  0.042229  0.0068979
9   3456_030_SGD  0.025792  0.0074630
10  3456_030_SGD  0.030255  0.0087543
11  3456_030_SGD  0.034683  0.0100356
12  3456_030_SGD  0.042194  0.0122089
```

Since `df` is passed as an argument between various functions, I'd rather not add other (intermediate?) columns to `df`, except for `baz`. Also, I'm looking for an efficient solution, because the dataframe can be quite large (way bigger than the small example above).

Comment: What exactly has the group of rows where foo has the same value to do with your calculation? According to your description, for each row, bar has to be divided by (FIRST_FOUR_DIGITS_ FOO) / 1000, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vectorized way:

```
df['baz'] = df['bar'].div(df['foo'].str[:4].astype(float).div(1000))

# OR

df['baz'] = df['bar'].div(df['foo'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float).div(1000))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
             foo       bar       baz
0   2410_030_GCD  0.012093  0.005018
1   2410_030_GCD  0.012789  0.005307
2   2410_030_GCD  0.014205  0.005894
3   2410_010_GCD  0.016280  0.006755
4   2410_010_GCD  0.019738  0.008190
5   6122_020_LCM  0.025806  0.004215
6   6122_020_LCM  0.030336  0.004955
7   6122_020_LCM  0.034753  0.005677
8   6122_020_LCM  0.042229  0.006898
9   3456_030_SGD  0.025792  0.007463
10  3456_030_SGD  0.030255  0.008754
11  3456_030_SGD  0.034683  0.010036
12  3456_030_SGD  0.042194  0.012209
```

Note: with `numpy`:

```
bar = df['bar'].values
foo = df['foo'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})', expand=False).values.astype(float)
df['baz'] = bar / (foo / 1000)
```

Comment: `str[:4]`  is not ok here because it's not guaranteed that the first 4 characters will contain digits (even though the example has this invariance, my bad).  It should still work 
 using `str.extract(r'(\d{4})')`, right?

Comment: Yes. It should. Can you update your question with a different sample, please? Don't forget to specify `expand=False`: `.str.extract(r'(\d{4})', expand=False)`

Comment: what does `expand=False` do?

Comment: It will create a Series instead of a DataFrame with one column. If you don't do that, math operations will produce NaN values (misaligned indexes)

Answer (score 1):

For speed, you may want to resort to a `numpy` approach:

```
df1['baz'] = (
    df1['bar'].values /
    (df1['foo'].str[:4].astype(float).values.flatten() / 1000))
```

Output:

```
             foo       bar       baz
0   2410_030_GCD  0.012093  0.005018
1   2410_030_GCD  0.012789  0.005307
2   2410_030_GCD  0.014205  0.005894
3   2410_010_GCD  0.016280  0.006755
4   2410_010_GCD  0.019738  0.008190
5   6122_020_LCM  0.025806  0.004215
6   6122_020_LCM  0.030336  0.004955
7   6122_020_LCM  0.034753  0.005677
8   6122_020_LCM  0.042229  0.006898
9   3456_030_SGD  0.025792  0.007463
10  3456_030_SGD  0.030255  0.008754
11  3456_030_SGD  0.034683  0.010036
12  3456_030_SGD  0.042194  0.012209
```

Comment: Nice! Could you compare it against @armin fastest solution?

Comment: I guess the comparison should be performed using a much larger dataframe, and not using the toy example provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have synthetically generated a 10k row dataset using this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random, string

for _ in range(10000):
    row = {
        'foo': f'{np.random.randint(1000, 10000)}_{np.random.randint(100, 1000)}_{''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=3))}',
        'bar': np.random.rand(),
    }
    df = df._append(row, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Will give this output:

```
               foo       bar
0     5749_558_XLI  0.958750
1     4804_197_QTY  0.391190
2     2918_660_VUB  0.981421
3     1429_687_UIL  0.598233
4     2677_697_IYA  0.298582
...            ...       ...
9995  6653_403_QAN  0.107291
9996  4990_398_UWB  0.917288
9997  3014_112_MJD  0.333702
9998  5740_427_YGO  0.052894
9999  7498_646_GHL  0.052835
```

Now let's try timing each method:

## Method 1

```py
import timeit
def f1():
     df['baz'] = df['bar'] / (df['foo'].str[:4].astype(float)/1000)

print(timeit.timeit(f1, number=1000))
```

`3.0309465489990544`

## Method 2

```py
import re

def extract_and_convert(foo):
     match = re.search(r'\d{4}', foo)
     if match:
         return float(match.group()) / 1000
     return None

def f2():
     df['baz'] = df['bar'] / df['foo'].apply(extract_and_convert)

timeit.timeit(f2, number=1000)
```

`10.555637381999986`

## Method 3 @Corralien

```py
def f3():
    df['baz'] = df['bar'].div(df['foo'].str[:4].astype(float).div(1000))

timeit.timeit(f3, number=10000)
```

`2.9525163210000755`

## Method 4 @Corralien

```py
def f4():
     df['baz'] = df['bar'].div(df['foo'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float).div(1000))
```

`5.99028635600007`

## Method 5 @PaulS

```py
def f5():
    df['baz'] = (df['bar'].values / df['foo'].str[:4].astype(float).values.flatten() / 1000)
```

`2.910304159999214`

## Conclusion

Method 5 (using numpy) is the fastest method.

##### Refrences

- [How to divide columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439613/python-pandas-dividing-column-by-another-column)
- [How to select a substring in Pand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505847/substring-of-an-entire-column-in-pandas-dataframe)
- [How to use regex in filtering rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765987/19675594)

Comment: Cool! It would be nice to include @PaulS solution in your tests. Since it's based on `numpy`, it ought to be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

As per your instructions

```
df['temp_extracted'] = df['foo'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})').astype(float)

df['baz'] = df['bar'] / (df['extracted'] / 1000)

df.drop(columns=['temp_extracted'], inplace=True)
```

Output :

```
             foo       bar       baz
0   2410_030_GCD  0.012093  0.005018
1   2410_030_GCD  0.012789  0.005307
2   2410_030_GCD  0.014205  0.005894
3   2410_010_GCD  0.016280  0.006755
4   2410_010_GCD  0.019738  0.008190
5   6122_020_LCM  0.025806  0.004215
6   6122_020_LCM  0.030336  0.004955
7   6122_020_LCM  0.034753  0.005677
8   6122_020_LCM  0.042229  0.006898
9   3456_030_SGD  0.025792  0.007463
10  3456_030_SGD  0.030255  0.008754
11  3456_030_SGD  0.034683  0.010036
12  3456_030_SGD  0.042194  0.012209
```

This is an easy to understand fashion otherwise the

> temp_extracted

can be omitted and directly we can proceed